# Python: reading a column in a csv file, make sure to use the right case for an if statement

Tags: python, csv

i'm very much a newbie to python.  I've read a csv file correctly, and if i do a print(row[0]) in a for loop it prints the first column.  But now within the loop, i'd like to do a conditional.  Obviously using row[0] in it doesn't work.  what's the correct syntax?
here's my code

```
video_choice = input("What movie would you like to look up?  ")

# read the rows
for row in netflix_reader:
    If video_choice == row[0]:
        print(row[0])
```

Comment: Why "Obviously using `row[0]` in it doesn't work"? There's no reason why it shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
if video_choice in row[0]:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

nvm, I have the if as "If".  I'm def a newb